# Sequelize association eager causes error in connectorDAO

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

Using MySQL and sequelize@1.6.0-beta4 now I want to use this new feature supposed to fetch associated models.
So I have this:

```
self.Project.hasMany(self.Task, {as:'Tasks', foreignKey: 'projectID'});
```

Then using the following:

```
db.models.Project.findAll({where:{id:1}, include : ['Tasks']}).success(function(project){
    console.log("With assoc: " + JSON.stringify(project) );
});
```

Unfortunately I'm getting the following error:

```
node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/query-generator.js:143
        if (association.connectorDAO) {
                       ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'connectorDAO' of null
```

If I suppress the include statement it works well but obviously doesn't return the associated tasks.

Going into debug I found something interesting. The `include` statement looks for associations on the child object (Task). If I add the (unnecessary) following:

```
self.Task.belongsTo(self.Project);
```

I then don't have a error fired anymore but the child objects weren't fetched.
I fear there is a bug...

Besides, I'm using `JSON.stringify` since `.values` is not working (`undefined`). Why?

Answer (score 0):

You have to connect both models back and forth, otherwise you will get that error.

If nothing is fetched, `.values` will be undefined.

Comment: The problem is really that I see no query that would return tasks in the logs (neither join or sub-query)